# Federated Experience Manager (FXM) won't start

Tags: fxm

I have a site that was recently upgraded from v7.5 to v8.1.  When I click on Federated Experience Manager from the launchpad the page opens but I get the little Sitecore spinning square.  Nothing ever loads.  When I look in the logs I see an error that seems to indicate an indexing issue.  My guess is that the main page of FXM first reads an index or something.  Here is the error message in the log file.

> Exception: System.InvalidOperationException Message:
>   [Index=sitecore_fxm_domains_web, Crawler=SitecoreItemCrawler,
>   Database=web] Root item could not be found: /sitecore/system/Marketing
>   Control Panel/fxm/. Source: Sitecore.ContentSearch    at
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler.get_RootItem()    at
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler.IsAncestorOf(Item item)
>   at
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler.IsExcludedFromIndex(IIndexableUniqueId
>   indexableUniqueId, IndexEntryOperationContext operationContext,
>   Boolean checkLocation)    at
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler.Update(IProviderUpdateContext
>   context, IIndexableUniqueId indexableUniqueId,
>   IndexEntryOperationContext operationContext, IndexingOptions
>   indexingOptions)    at
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.AbstractSearchIndex.<>c__DisplayClass16.b__10(IndexableInfo
>   info, ParallelLoopState parallelLoopState)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClassf`1.b__c()
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvokeWithArg(Task childTask)
>   at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c__DisplayClass11.b__10(Object
>   param0)

It seems to be saying that it can't find the FXM root item: `/sitecore/system/Marketing Control Panel/fxm/`.  Although when I look in my content editor that item is clearly there.  I do notice that in my content tree the name of the item is capitalized `FXM` instead of all lower case `fxm`. Would that make a difference?  I also notice that my Solr indexes for FXM (master and web) have nothing in them at all.  Is that normal if you haven't set anything up yet for FXM?

EDIT:
In addition when I look in the browser console when trying to load FXM I see the following:

> Uncaught Failed to data-bind: ProgressIndicator -
>   TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'attributes' of undefined - sitecore-1.0.2.js:2092

Comment: Do you have the `fxm` item in the web database as well?

Comment: Yes it is in the web database also.

Comment: Item path is case-insensitive when using `database.GetItem()` (which is what the code in question is using). So it actually can't find the item. Please double check that the `FXM` item that exists in your content tree has an identical path to the one in the error message.

Comment: Interesting.  The code seem to be looking for lower case `fxm` but the item in the content tree is upper case `FXM`.  The content item is protected so I don't think I can change that.  How would I change the code to look for `FXM`? To me this seems like a Sitecore bug. This is just a normal 8.1 install.

Comment: As I have mentioned above, the casing of the item name is irrelevant. `GetItem()` is case-insensitive. You can try to change the path in `Sitecore.FXM.Solr.DomainsSearch.Index.Web.config` and `Sitecore.FXM.Solr.DomainsSearch.Index.Master.config`, but I don't believe this can help you.

Comment: Oh sorry - I misread your comment.

Comment: Clear item caches via `/sitecore/admin/cache.aspx`, then try to rebuild FXM indexes in the Control Panel -> Indexing manager.

Answer (score 4):

It turns out that there is a bug in Sitecore related to EXM and FXM files on the same instance.  Sitecore Support pointed me to the following hotfix package that fixed the problem I was having: https://dl.sitecore.net/hotfix/Sitecore%20CMS%208.1%20rev.%20160519%20Hotfix%20119569-1.zip.