# FXM Domain Dashboard Spinner Run Continuously

Tags: fxm

I am using sitecore 8.1 (rev. 160519) and it is updated from 7.5. I am facing error on FXM Domain Dashboard page i.e the spinner run continuously and in console i saw below error,

```
Uncaught Failed to data-bind: ProgressIndicator TypeError: Cannot read property 'attributes' of undefined.
```

I try to rebuild FXM indexs but still it is given same error. So can anyone help me to resolve this.

Comment: are you using EXM on this solution ?

Comment: Yes we are using EXM. So is there any configuration changes which i have to make to work this ?

Comment: I guess it's a bug. please see release notes for 8.2 update 1 where it was fixed a bug https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform/82/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform%2082%20Update1/Release%20Notes nr 119569

Comment: Thank you so much for suggestion , i will follow the same , I am new to Sitecore so i have one doubt that i am using sitecore 8.1 (rev. 160519) , so release notes for 8.2 update 1  is also applicable for 8.1 version or i should have search for release note for 8.1 ?

Comment: In 8.2 it was solved this problem. So I guess this bug is replicable to 8.1

Comment: Thanks for quick response, So on uat enviorment which is same as our prod , there it is working fine but on prod we are facing this issue. So for FXM to work shall we have to upgrade from 8.1 to 8.2 , or is there any package fix which can resolve this ?

Comment: Please write to Sitecore Support.

Comment: Thanks , i will do the same , and let you know the reply which i get from Sitecore Support

Comment: Hi Climber , you are right it was a bug , after searching i found one similar post in which sitecore support suggested to install a hotfix package , so after installing this package fxm is now working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Finally the error was resolved after installing a hotfix package please refer to below link using which my problem was resolved.

[Federated Experience Manager (FXM) won't start](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/2762/federated-experience-manager-fxm-wont-start)